# Python: Writing a matrix with different values depending of how far is from a point (i,j)

Tags: python, matrix

Help me out with this code! As Input I have N: matrix size. i: point's row. j: point's column. P: point's magnitude. Each time I move away point (i,j) the magnitude will decrease -1. So if my input is N = 7, i = 3, j = 3, P = 3, my output would look like this:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 1 1 1 1 0

0 1 2 2 2 1 0

0 1 2 **3** 2 1 0

0 1 2 2 2 1 0

0 1 1 1 1 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I can't figure out how to write the correct value in each position :( help me out! [Here's the code that I tried -->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4uyS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a beautiful or efficient solution, but gets the work done:

```
N, i, j, P = 7, 3, 3, 3

M = [[0] * N for i in range(N)]
for row in range(N):
    for col in range(N):
        M[row][col] = P - max(abs(row - i), abs(col - j))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! For the purpose, it works perfectly :)